# T-SQL string concatenation `'string' + str(integer)` introduces extra space character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry for the somewhat trivial question, but why does

```
select ('https://stackoverflow.com/users/' + str(Id)) as Link
from Users
where DisplayName = 'Jon Skeet';
```

when entered into the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) return

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/ 22656
```

instead of

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656
```

?

According to Microsoft's [documentation on T-SQL's `+` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017),

```
'book' + 'case'
```

should give

```
'bookcase'
```

not

```
'book case'
```

and according to [the Data Explorer documentation](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), the SQL-flavor used in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer is indeed T-SQL.

---

Some additional experiments:

```
select str(42);
```

returns `"42"`, without extra spaces *(see EDIT below)*.

```
select ('foo' + 'bar');
```

returns `"foobar"`, also without spaces.

```
select ('foo' + '42');
```

returns `"foo42"`, so it doesn't treat digits specially or anything like that.

---

To me, it looks as if basic semantic compositionality principle is violated. What am I missing here?

---

**EDIT** The problem turned out to be the wrong assumption that

```
select str(42);
```

returns `"42"`. It actually returns

```
"        42"
```

but the spaces are ignored by the browser-based GUI.

Here is another example that demonstrates the problem more clearly:

```
select 'foo' + str('42');
```

seems to return

```
"foo 42"
```

but it actually returns

```
"foo        42"
```

as can be seen in this query:

```
select LEN('foo' + str('42'));
```

which returns 13 (not 5 and also not 6). Many thanks @lad2025 for pointing this out.

So, it was mostly an "optical illusion" caused by a somewhat inaccurate representation of string-results in the browser.

Comment: I'm going to guess ID isn't numeric.  What datatype is ID?  varchar?  if so ID contains the extra space.

Comment: [The documnentation for `str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) says:  "A short float_expression is **right-justified** in the specified length, and a long float_expression is truncated to the specified number of decimal places. For example, STR(12,10) yields the result of 12. **This is right-justified in the result set**."

Comment: @xQbert It says `int`.

Comment: The issue is with `STR` function

Comment: `select ('foo' + str('42'));` would give you `foo 42` then  why not allow the implicit conversion?  @Mazhar I agree now after type is defined.  I'd use cast/convert or let implicit conversion handle it then.

Comment: **(Spaces invisible in comment inline-code, so replaced spaces by `-`)** Ok, so, the `select str(42);` returns `"---------42"` instead of `"42"`, but the spaces are ignored by the browser-based GUI. Here is another example that demonstrates the problem more clearly:

    select 'foo' + str('42');

seems to return `"foo-42"`, but it actually returns `"foo--------42"`, as can be seen in this query:

    select LEN('foo' + str('42'));

which returns `13` (not `5` and also not `6`). Many thanks @lad2025 for pointing this out.

Comment: select str(42); does not return "42" with no extra spaces.

Comment: @paparazzo Should I move my previous comment into the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is [`STR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns character data converted from numeric data.
>
> STR ( float_expression [ , **length** [ , decimal ] ] )
>
> Is the total length. This includes decimal point, sign, digits, and spaces. **The default is 10.**

```
select REPLACE(str(Id), ' ', '-')
from Users
where DisplayName = 'Jon Skeet';

OUTPUT:
-----22656
```

I would simply use `CONCAT`:

```
select CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/users/', id) AS link
from Users
where DisplayName = 'Jon Skeet';
```

**[See Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/855631)**

Comment: Is then the `"42"` output for `str(42)` merely an artifact of the browser-based GUI that ignores whitespace?

Comment: concat applies implicit conversion of the int datatype to string then right?

Comment: @xQbert Yes, the is implicit cast

Comment: @AndreyTyukin `SELECT LEN(str(42))` -- 10 **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c3e945d9980f79ec6018191b61acc0e)**

Comment: Yes, and also `select LEN('foo' + str('42'));` returns `13`, not `5` or `6`. It's just the browser-based GUI that hides the extra spaces. Thank you, that explains it.